# Python can't find 'main' module

Tags: python, program-entry-point

When I run the code using the command `python filename.py`, I am getting the following error,

`/Library/anaconda/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in filename.py`

I am not sure what exactly is going wrong here. I need help correcting this.
How can I correct this?

```
SUFFIXES = {1000: ['KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'],
            1024: ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB']}

def approximate_size(size, a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes=True):
    '''Convert a file size to human-readable form.

    Keyword arguments:
    size -- file size in bytes
    a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes -- if True (default), use multiples of 1024
                                if False, use multiples of 1000

    Returns: string

    '''
    if size < 0:
        raise ValueError('number must be non-negative')

    multiple = 1024 if a_kilobyte_is_1024_bytes else 1000
    for suffix in SUFFIXES[multiple]:
        size /= multiple
        if size < multiple:
            return '{0:.1f} {1}'.format(size, suffix)

    raise ValueError('number too large')

if __name__ == “__main__”:
    print(“Hello World”)
    print(approximate_size(1000000000000, False))
    print(approximate_size(1000000000000))
```

Answer (score 23):

It's because of the quote marks you are using. Change the `“`s to `"`s

Comment: Let this be a lesson not to copy paste from wordpress blogs.

Comment: what is the difference between `"` and `"` ? this did not solve the problem for me unfortunately.  Also, I only see one double quotes on my keyboard.

Comment: @user391339 it's not `"` and `"`, it's `“` and `“`. `“` is a unicode character rather than ascii, and is not on a standard keyboard layout. please see https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C for more info. it is likely that you are having a different issue if this did not solve yours.